# Is there any method to unescape '&gt;' to '>' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to escape some HTML in JavaScript.  How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what's so terrible about str.replace? Does it not work?

Comment: Because you have more entities than just that.  for example, &arr; &larr; &rarr; &bull; etc...  Oh, and you have those non-english characters and `*gasp*` accents and the like

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I often use the following function to decode [HTML Entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references):

```
function htmlDecode(input){
  var e = document.createElement('div');
  e.innerHTML = input;
  return e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}

htmlDecode('&lt;&gt;'); // "<>"
```

Simple, cross-browser and works with all the [HTML 4 Character Entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html).

Comment: Thanks mate. Btw via jQuery it will look like var str='&lt;&gt;';
$('<div>'+str+'</div>').text();

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dummy textarea, set its innerHTML to your escaped html [the html with `&gt;s`] and use the textarea.value

```
var ta = document.createElement('textarea');
 ta.innerHTML = "&gt;";
 alert(ta.value);
```

... had to use this on a CMS once [although when i used it, it was bad practice]